How to implement a Dynamic UITableView inside a Static UITableView?
For a screen, I have used a UITableviewController with a static cell. All of the UIComponents such as label, image, buttons are defined inside this static cell.
Now, I need to have a dynamic tableview inside this cell. Its height is not fixed. It has to vary based on the number of cells it contains.
here's how the delegate and datasource looks like
    override func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
            return 1
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        if tableView.tag == 2 {
            return 3
        }
        return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        if tableView.tag == 2 {
            let cell = (tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: Constant.ReuseIdentifiers.offersViewCell) as? OffersTableViewCell)!
            return cell
        }
        return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
    }
    
    override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if tableView.tag == 2 {
            // Do something when a dynamic row is selected
        } else {
            super.tableView(tableView, didSelectRowAt: indexPath)
        }
    }

When I run the application and navigate to this screen, it fails with an error "Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSSingleObjectArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'"
how to differentiate the datasource/delegate methods for this static tableview and dynamic tableview.
Earlier when there was no dynamic tableview, I didn't have to implement these methods but now I believe that's where the problem lies. Any suggestions or ideas?
I also tried, the Dynamic Tableview with a fixed height. Still it was failing with the same error. So, how to implement this correctly. I can make this tableview resizable later

Generally not a good idea to embed a table view in a table view cell. See if you can re-think your layout to avoid that.

This is why the delegate and the datasource pass to you the tableView. You should ideally have a UITableView subclass then call if let myClass = tableView as? MyClass { You could also tag the view or use some other property to id it.

Are you registering your cell with the tableview?
